# can't use dea function of Benchmarking package in R

Tags: r

I'm using Benchmarking package to run a model of data envelopment analysis using dea function on it. In addition, I'm using nonparaeff package, for partial frontier, which has a function called dea too. This similarity in name function produces this "error":

> Attaching package: ‘nonparaeff’
> The following object is masked from ‘package:Benchmarking’:

So, is it possible to use both packages at the same time or not?

Comment: Which object is being masked from package:Benchmarking?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use both packages.

> Attaching package: ‘nonparaeff’ The following object is masked from ‘package:Benchmarking’:

This error message basically means, that the package you loaded last (in this case `nonparaeff`) masks functions from `Benchmarking`.

The first thing to mention is:
All other functions without naming conflicts will work as expected.

The second thing to take care of is:
When you just call `dea()` in your code now, you will call the function from the package last loaded. (because the other package's `dea()` function is masked by this function)

But, to be sure to call the right function you can just write the functions calls like this : `Benchmarking::dea()` and `nonparaeff::dea()`.

By specifying `packagename::funtionname()` you make sure to call exactly the function from the specified package. It is not as convenient as calling just `dea()`, but in case of functions with the same name, I would actually use this for both functions. (to prevent mistakes)

I myself quite often call my functions with `packagename::funtionname()` - it avoids errors and another positive is, you directly know by looking at the code, from which package a function is.

Comment: Thank you for everythiing, helps a lot !!